# Drywall repair- mesh tape vs California patch

Tags: patching-drywall

I recently updated my washer box and am now looking to patch a small area on the stud, which I've highlighted in red. I can see two ways I could do this, one is to cut out a piece for this repair and use mesh tape. Alternatively, I can also use California patch.

I'm fairly new to drywall repairs, is there one method better than the other? Would an all-purpose mud from Home Depot be suitable for this task?[image: Area needs to be patched]

[image: Precise patch]

[image: California patch]

Comment: Why not cut all the way up and down the right side of that notch and just replace the entire big hole at once?  I assume you're not planning to leave that open.

Answer (score 1):

I would draw a line down the middle of that stud and remove the drywall from the left half of the stud, so that you have a surface for attaching the right edges of your patch.  If you don't do that, this little bump off to the side is going to be the least of the challenges.

Then, I assume, you're going to pop off the bezel of the washer box, measure one big piece of drywall, and fit it to fill the opening.  A couple strips of wood behind the top and bottom of the patch will help hold the drywall boards together.

It's a judgement call whether to tape the edges of a patch like this one, and I can't even see all of it in the photos.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only repairing the area you marked in red, then either way  will work (mesh tape or california patch). I find the mesh tape a bit easier to work with. And yes, regular all purpose mud is fine for a small job like this.